# Do you have examples to "...it is evaluated only once when using __auto_type, but twice if typeof is used. "?

Tags: c, gnu

> If the argument to the macro has variably modified type, it is
>   evaluated only once when using __auto_type, but twice if typeof is
>   used.

From the end of this file: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Can someone provide me examples of a situation that would cause code to break, in runtime, if `typeof` is used in place of `__auto_type` ?

Comment: What is "unwanted behaviour"?

Comment: A bug :) is an unwanted behavior.

Comment: Is your question "what is a variably-modified type?" or is it "under what circumstances would it be a problem to evaluate a macro argument more than once?"

Comment: @FelipeLavratti: Please provide a reference to the C standard which defines "unwanted behavior" or "bug". That comment of mine was meant serious. Think about it!

Comment: The second, what circumstances it would break code to evaluate the macro more than once, note that typeof is usually removed in build time.

Comment: @Olaf i have edited the question, let me know if it is clearer now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remark in comments

> note that typeof is usually removed in build time

and that seems to underscore the crux of your confusion.  Although `typeof` is a GNU extension, not standard C, it is analogous to C's `sizeof` in that, it is only *usually* computed at build time.  As the GNU doc to which you linked puts it,

> The operand of `typeof` is evaluated for its side effects if and only if it is an expression of variably modified type or the name of such a type.

Whether the `typeof` itself corresponds to runtime code in that case is not really the point (though it probably *does* correspond to runtime code in that case); the point is that the macro argument is evaluated at runtime in the context of the `typeof` operation.  If that evaluation produces any side effects, then there is a difference between `typeof` and `__auto_type` with respect to how many times those side effects are applied, and possibly even in what the side effects are.

It is admittedly a bit tricky to construct an example of an expression that has variably-modified type and whose evaluation produces non-trivial side effects, but we can fall back on good old autoincrement / autodecrement here.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPEOF_EX(p) do { \
    __typeof__(p) _q = (p);    \
    printf("typeof yields: %d\n", (*_q)[1]); \
} while (0)

#define AUTOTYPE_EX(p) do { \
    __auto_type _q = (p);  \
    printf("__auto_type yields: %d\n", (*_q)[1]); \
} while (0)

int main(void) {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    int a[x][y];
    int (*p)[y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            a[i][j] = i * y + j;
        }
    }

    p = a;
    TYPEOF_EX(++p);

    p = a;
    AUTOTYPE_EX(++p);
}
```

The program produces the following output for me:

> typeof yields: 11
>
> __auto_type yields: 6

Comment: Better prefix names in the macro with single underscore. That reduces the probability of collisions.

Comment: Considering this is indeed the same as `sizeof`, "evaluation" refers to processing the expression to get the actual type (i.e. how the array-length is to be calculated), but does not necessarily means the side-effects are executed twice.

Comment: @Olaf, ok, I have prefixed the variable names, but in this case it does not reduce the probability of a collision, because probabilities cannot go below zero.  The variable declared inside each macro is scoped to the block in which it is declared -- it may shadow another variable of the same name, but that is not problematic.

Comment: 1) If recommended warnings are enabled, shadowing will generate a warning. 2) worse: what if `q` was passed as argument?

Comment: @Olaf, My answer includes a quote from the GNU docs that seems to contradict your assertion about the meaning of "evaluation".  Note that the docs explicitly say that the expression is evaluated *for its side effects*.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, shadowing may generate a warning. I'm not too much concerned with that, and anyway prefixing cannot be *certain* to avoid it, but ok.  That the actual argument may collide with the name of the variable declared inside the macro is a good catch, though, as actual breakage could occur.  Prefixing cannot completely avoid that, either, but minimizing the likelihood of this is indeed a worthy objective.

Comment: I well see this is a problem and you might be correct. But that would be different from `sizeof` which they reference as similar (and which sounds legit). Sure "evaluate for the side-effects" does imply "execute the side-effects"?. Did you test the code?

Comment: Yes, they mention in the docs there is an unavoidable probability for collisions. But as one normally does not use `_` -prefixed names as local variables and they are reserved for the implementation at file-scope, I suspect there was not much pressure to provide a better way.

Comment: @Olaf, I have converted the original example code to a runnable example that indeed demonstrates a difference.  I had to do this at ideone, not otherwise having a new enough GCC, and to support their compilation options I had to use the alternate syntax `__typeof__` instead of unadorned `typeof`.  But yes, now I can say that I have tested it.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and I will keep that in mind. So better use `__auto_type` where possible (I didn't even know about that one). I still wonder what the reason would be.

Comment: @Olaf, I cannot speak to why GNU's `typeof` behaves as it does, but I do note that its docs are subtly but importantly different in form from the standard's specification's for `sizeof`.  The standard specifies that the operand of `sizeof` is evaluated if and only if it is a VLA (6.5.3.4/2), whereas GNU `typeof` is documented to evaluate the operand if it has *any kind* of variably-modified type.

Comment: Hold it! So the output is `a[1][1]` for `__auto_type` and `a[2][1]` for `typeof`. But that does not say the side-effect `++p` is executed twice for `typeof`, but once for `typeof` and once for the initialiser! If the side-effect was executed twice for `typeof`, we had `a[3][1]` (which was UB, but let's ignore this for a moment). Looks like the code supports my interpretation - or that's the actual point and I completely did not see the problem.

Comment: @Olaf, yes.  The operand of `typeof` is evaluated, once, for its side effects if it is or has a variably-modified type, but otherwise it is not evaluated (for its side effects) at all.  In my examples, it is evaluated when it is used as an initializer as well.  I used this form because it is typical of the style of a macro that is attempting to avoid evaluating its arguments multiple times.  After all, that's one of the primary use cases of `typeof` and `__auto_type`.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit slow today. Makes perfectly sense now. Problem seems to be the citation in the question which is completely out of context. To sum up: the problem is not the double-evaluation, but that it is not evaluated for non-variably modified type. Btw: which variably-modified type olther than VLA do you have in mind?

Comment: @Olaf, in my example, the variably-modified type is pointer-to-VLA, not VLA.  Function types with VLA arguments are also considered variably modified, as are pointers to and arrays of all of the above, etc..  Details are at [6.7.6/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6p3), as further explained at [6.2.5/24](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p24).

Comment: Awesome. Nothing clearer than a nice piece of code. Thanks @JohnBollinger

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I should have said "types which don't involve VLAs - directly or indirectly". So we agree the only variably modified type **are** VLAs,m resp. types which are derived from one in any way.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, we agree: the only variably modified types are VLA types and types derived from VLA types.  These are designated "variably modified" by section 6.7.6/3 of the standard, and that serves as the definition of the term, for as far as I can determine, nowhere else does the standard designate any type to be variably modified.

Comment: I wasn't aware this is a standard term. Thanks for your patience.